# Как воспроизвести звук при нажатии на клавишу?

Tags: python, if, pygame, условия

Хочу, чтобы когда вводилась 1 раз цифра, то 1 раз воспроизводился звук.

Вот код:

```
from pygame import mixer


def sound():
    mixer.init()
    mixer.music.load("123.mp3")
    mixer.music.play()
    input()

print ('Нажмите, чтобы играть')

press_key = input()

if press_key <= 5:
    sound()
```

Ошибка, которая возникает:

```
File "c:\Users\Администратор\Desktop\поп ит ентертеймант\python part\algoritm.py", line 14, in <module>
   if press_key <= 5:
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: "вводил 1 раз цифру": любую или только "5"?

Comment: и вам `'<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'` ни о чем не говорит?

Comment: одну цифру, если она равна или меньше пяти, то звук должен выводиться

Comment: а как тогда мне решить проблему с '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), проголосуйте за ответ и отметьте его [галочкой](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) как решение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

буквально означает, что сравнивать строку и целое - дело неблагодарное... попробуйте так:

```
from pygame import mixer


def sound():
    mixer.init()
    mixer.music.load("123.mp3")
    mixer.music.play()

press_key = input('Нажмите 1-5, чтобы играть')

if press_key in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']:
    sound()
```

или даже так:

```
if press_key in '12345':
    sound()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Понял как это работает. Что-ж с юниора взять))